# Easy airplane program

Tags: general-aviation

I'm 67 and would like a recommended easy airplane program to play. I cannot afford to really learn to fly so I would like something that is not to complicated to use.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi John. Are you looking for specifically a computer game with joystick for control, or would a tablet game be ok?

Comment: By airplane program do you mean a flight simulator?

Answer (score 4):

A short(ish) version: for a tabletop computer or a laptop with Windows, any of the Microsoft Flight Simulator series will be fine. They are easy to use, and as you get better, you can add more and more realism.

If you want good graphics, these kind of games typically require quite a powerful computer, but a basic setup will get you started.

If I recall correctly, from MS FS 2004 onwards, you even get other planes flying around, and there is air traffic control you can communicate with via preset phrases.

MS should release a new version in the coming months, but I would remommend an older version, as one can probably find the a ta fraction of the price of the coming version[(Amazon.co.uk less than 10£](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Flight-Simulator-2004-Century/dp/B00009WAPR)).

You should make sure the version you are about to buy is compatible with your Windows version. MS FS 2004 for example should run fine with Windows 10.

There is also [X-Plane](https://www.x-plane.com/), I tried one years and years ago, but I recall it being not as easy to use. Flying I guess was pretty much the same: close enough for the real thing.

Comment: I'm an alpha-tester for the upcoming Microsoft FS... you should beware that it is a *83 gigabyte download (currently, this will probably go up)*, and no, I'm not at all kidding.

Comment: Excellent point, older version come on dvd's. Will the 2020 be download only?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, and as much as I'm aware an internet connection is required to play it. Downloading 83 GB on my 14Mb DSL connection was a 4 day affair...